# Existe algum servidor online onde eu possa enviar um formulário feito em Android com JSon para testar?

Tags: android, web-service

Só para testar se meu aplicativo está funcionando. Algo bem simples mesmo que recebe meu formulário em formato JSon.

Answer (score 1):

Tem um WebService bacana pra você fazer esse teste:

é para fazer busca de endereço pelo CEP

http://viacep.com.br/ws/**passa o CEP aqui**/json/

exemplo: http://viacep.com.br/ws/01001-000/json/

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está procurando uma hospedagem gratuita. Então, você pode usar esta:

https://byethost.com/index.php/free-hosting

Comment: Não, o que estou procurando é um servidor para testar a minha aplicação android, um servidor que receba o json e exiba.